# How to make a dropdownlist from sql to be displayed in listbox asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my code and I'm new to C# and trying to learn, basically I have a project where specialists are being scheduled in their specialty using fullcalendar, but when I created the dropdownlist for specialty and then made a listbox for the specialist in each specialty being selected it keeps saying that there's an error on cmd.ExecuteScalar(); What am I doing wrong?

````
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT id, name, active, modifiedDate, note FROM sldb.dbo.Services", con);
                    con.Open();
                    DropDownList1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "name";
                    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "id";

                    DropDownList1.DataBind();

                }
            }
        }

 protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 if(this.DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value != "0")
            {
                String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
                {
                    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select firstName from sldb.dbo.Specilist where serviceID= @serviceID", con))
                    {

                        using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                        {

                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@serviceID", this.DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);
                            con.Open();
                            object firstName = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                            con.Close();
                            this.ListBox1.Text = firstName.ToString();

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.ListBox1.Text = "Please select name from list";
            }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

If the error is on `ExecuteScalar`, there is something wrong with your query. I'm noticing Specialist is spelled wrong in the select statement. Try correcting that and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

note that executeScalar return the first column of the first row in the dataset. Try wrap the executescalar in a try catch

```
 try
 {
     object firstName = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
 }
 catch(Exception error)
 {
      //display error message error.Message;
 }
```

Step through the code, I'd be tempted to put the value in a string to see what Scalar is returning.

```
    string strPeek = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Also, run the SQL separately to be sure the query is not erroneous.